# Is $1$ Limit point of the sequence $(-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Is the element $'1'$ Limit point of the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$

As per the definition of Limit point we have:

A point $p$ is said to be an Limit point of a sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ iff Every $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q$ in the sequence other than $p$

Now suppose in the given sequence if $1$ is the Limit point and if we choose $\epsilon=0.1$ Then we have neighborhood as $(0.9, 1.1)$ which contains the element only as $1$

So Is $1$ a Limit point?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are mixing two distinct concepts here: the concept of limit point of a *set* and the concept of limit point of a *sequence*. We say that $x$ is a limit point of a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ if, for every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_n\in V$. Under this definition, it is clear that $1$ is a limit point of the sequence $\bigl((-1)^n\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

On the other hand, we say that $x$ is a limit point of the set $S$ if, for every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, $V$ contains some element of $S$ distinct from $x$. This is close to what you wrote but, as you see, it is a different concept.

Comment: There is an important relation between limit point of a set and sequence, Consider this theorem: A point $x ∈ R$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $A$ with $a_n \neq x$ for all $n ∈ N$, and $limn→∞ a_n = x$

Comment: But every sequence is a set right?

Comment: No. A sequence of elements of $X$ is a *map* from $\mathbb N$ into $X$. The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not the same thing as the set $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$.